# User Specific Remote Desktop Connection Settings

Tags: remote-desktop, group-policy, windows-server

I have around 90 users connecting to our Windows Server 2016, throughout the remote desktop service.

I wonder if there are any group policies where I can enable;

- Some users to open multiple sessions: If a connected same user tries to log in, the existing connection will not get affected
- Limit some users to a single session: If a connected same user tries to log in, the existing connection will be disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft there is a way. I've never tried it, but here it is:

This Group Policy setting is located in `Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host\Connections` and can be configured by using either the Local Group Policy Editor or the Group Policy Management Console (GPMC).

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753380(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: You'll need to set up a Group for each type of RD profile and add the appropriate users to each group. Then create the Group Policies and use filtering to apply them to each specific group. This way you can have different policies applied to different people, and changing people's policies is as simple as moving them to a different AD Group.